# Is there a way to inherit static function invoking constructor of child class with parameters?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, abstract

I have got a lot of classes inheriting from an abstract class. I would like to have a static method returning new object for each one of them and was wondering if I can't shorten the code like this:

```
class Foo : Bar
{
    // I don't want to write this in every child class
    public static Foo create(paramsFoo) => new Foo(paramsFoo);
}

abstract class Bar
{
    // is something like this possible without using generics?
    public static "getchildtype" create("paramsofchild") => new "getchildtype"("paramsofchild")
    // if not, is there a way to do that with generics?
    // would it be possible if there were no parameters?
}
```

I know I could just use the word "new" but I like the way this would look:

```
something += Foo.create(params);
```

Comment: you should look at the [factory-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: It would also really help if you would write even pseudo-code in as realistic a way as possible, following naming conventions and following existing C# syntax as closely as possible. (I don't know what `paramsFoo` means in your `create` method declaration, because the method declaration isn't valid.)

Comment: Just use `new`, move on with life and solve bigger problems :)

Comment: If children need all different sets of params, there is no point in unifying a create method.

Comment: _"// would it be possible if there were no parameters?"_  => `public static T Create<T>()  where T : Bar, new()` - but that would have no obvious benefit over `new Foo()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.